# Text Layer google-maps-api-3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have been working with the Google Maps API V3 on a project for some time.  I am using the polygon shapes to represent buildings on the map of my campus and now I'm looking for a solution to the issue of the shapes being underneath the text for the map.  This includes building games in specific for my campus.  I was wondering if there was a way to move the order in which they are displayed so that polygons go under the built in text layer for google maps, and if so, how I would achieve that.

Thanks in advanced,
Mike

Comment: Are you talking about text such as Cities and Roads? You want the polygon to be "below" the text so you're not seeing (for example) the coloring effects of the polygon on the labels?

Comment: Yes, I would like the polygons to appear below the text for cities, roads, and buildings.  Not so they don't appear but so that the names are no obscured by the polygon.  I have the opacity down but it still needs to be completely visable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Unless the map names are turned off via map options they appear to be a part of the tile image.

Edit: You could possibly do something like turn off the labels and use a library like infobox to make your own.